# How to show Confirm Dialog Box always remains on top of any application?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am doing one web application in PHP.

I am showing one *JavaScript confirm dialog-box* on `window focus-out event` but i want it to remains always on top of the screen and without responding to confirm dialog box user can not open any windows application or any other browser tab.

I am doing time calculation based on the confirm dialog box response.

Comment: You can't prevent user to use OS with JS.

Comment: Fortunately, this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Be more precise why you are trying to achive this and why. User can prevent javascript from executing in his browser, it is bad use it for these kind of security checks. User can also click on x button and not to confirm.